# Removing item from Datagrid view with delete button

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove a value from the data i import into a DGV, the code i have so far is:

```
private GArrayList<int> idList = new GArrayList<int>();

private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int listIndex;
  IDStruct idValue;
  DialogResult dialogResult;

  listIndex = this.displayDGV.CurrentRow.Index + 1;
  idValue = idList[listIndex]; <---- Error here
  dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Delete " + idValue.Index.ToString("d4") + " " +
                                  idValue.ID, "Delete Value",
                                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
  if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
  {
    this.idList.RemoveAt(listIndex);
    //this.RefreshClientAreaControls(listIndex);
  }
}
```

The error i get is cannot implicitly convert type int to IDStruct.
the IDStruct is a class i made, here is the code in that class:

```
public class IDStruct
{
  private int index;
  private int id;

  public IDStruct(int indexValue, int idValue)
  {
    this.Index = indexValue;
    this.ID = idValue;
  }

  public int Index
  {
    get
    {
      return this.index;
    }
    set
    {
      this.index = value;
    }
  }

  public int ID
  {
    get
    {
      return this.id;
    }
    set
    {
      this.id = value;
    }
  }
}  // End class IDStruct
```

}
}

The error obviously is correct, but i'm not sure exactly how to write the syntax and could use some direction. Any help would be awesome! I've tried to research for some help, but haven't had much luck. I'm still new to c#.

Thank You!

Comment: Which instruction gives you the error?

Comment: `idValue = idList[listIndex];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement you've stated as throwing an error is assigning a value of type int to idValue which has a type of IDStruct. Of course you know that as you've accepted that the error is correct.

If idList is the data being fed into the DGV then why even use the idValue?

I would think that if idList contains the data for the DGV then delete it directly. No need for idValue.

If you are trying to assign the value to the IDStruct then you will need to call the setter method of idValue corresponding to the property you wish to change.